# return a single message from array of messages

Tags: java

I just have requirement that i have an array of type Messages. so i want to return a Messages from them. Can anyone help me how to do that?

```
public static Message getContent(String user, String pswd, String sub, String to)
        throws MessagingException, IOException {
    Session imapSession1 = TestMail.greenMail.getImap().createSession();
    Store store = imapSession1.getStore("imap");
    store.connect("foo", "password");
    Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
    inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
    // Getting only unread messages.
    Flags flags = new Flags();
    flags.add(Flag.SEEN);
    FlagTerm flagTerm = new FlagTerm(flags, false);
    Message[] msgs = inbox.search(flagTerm);
    Message ms = msgs[0];
    return ms;

}
```

I tried to return first message as shown above, but it is throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
So can anyone help me with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That means `inbox.search` is returning an empty array. We can't help you with that.

Answer (score 0):

Either there is a problem with your previous code or there are no unread messages but either way `msgs` is empty after you have search the inbox - you just need to check `msgs.length > 0` first and if it is not then decide what you want to do. You could return an Optional (Java8 feature and you would need to change the method signature to match) or simply return null or throw an exception depending on your needs. All 3 scenarios then need appropriate handling in the calling code.

NOTE that it is unlikely that throwing an Exception is the correct approach unless the code is only called when there should be unread messages.

Comment: okay. but when i used this code in my testng class it shows that there is one message. I'm passing that as a static string. but i want to shift that implementation of my testng class to normal class and trying to call that method. so it is giving me that error.

Comment: Well the irrefutable fact is that `msgs` is empty so I think the focus of your question is wrong. You need to post a question that focuses instead on what your testng implementation is (as well as the code above) and **why** `msgs` is empty.

Comment: I debug that and saw i got classnot loaded exception by debugger.

`org.eclipse.debug.core.DebugException: com.sun.jdi.ClassNotLoadedException: Type has not been loaded occurred while retrieving component type of array`

Comment: do you know what might cause this?

Comment: Actually i changed the code and can return a message. but the thing is when i'm trying to write any code in my test method other than assert function, the test is getting failed . if there is only assert statement then my test case passed. i don't why this happens.